# Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/libc-bin_2.15-0ubuntu10.6_i386.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

Tags: apt, alien

Hi While executing the command at root -

```
apt-get install alien
```

I get below errors (page not found)

Can you please fix / help

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc-bin i386 2.15-0ubuntu10.6
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libc-bin i386 2.15-0ubuntu10.6
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
```

Answer (score 97):

As you can see at

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/eglibc/

, this version is not in the repo anymore. This is most probably caused by an outdated apt cache, i. e. you haven't issued an

```
apt-get update
```

before. Try it again with

```
apt-get update && apt-get install alien
```

Comment: It sometimes also helps to add `--fix-missing`, as in `apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install <package>`.

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer to solve the thing

Comment: Same happens to me for curl installation. **--fix-missing** increase the build to from seconds to almost 10 min :S